# error: invalid use of non-static data member 'capacity' int data[capacity];

Tags: c++

I don't understand why data is the only variable in private that is causing me problems.  Originally I thought I might be able to fix the problem by declaring the variables for the first time in the constructor, but I feel like there must be a way to define the variables privately and then set them in the constructor without any problems.  How do I fix this?  Also what does it mean by invalid use of non-static data memory?

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class stack{
private: 
    int capacity;
    int data[capacity];
    int top;
    int bottom;


public:
   stack(){
        top=0;
        bottom=0;
        capacity=100;
   }

   bool isEmpty(){
        return top==bottom;
   }

   int pop(stack S){
        //assert(!isEmpty());
        int elem = data[top];
        top--;
        return elem;  
   }

   void push(stack S,int x){
        assert(top<capacity-1);
        top++;
        data[top]=x;
        return;
   }

};

int main()
{
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: kalkid, just out of interest, if you're not allowed to use vectors (as per one of your comments), why do you have `#include <vector>` in your code? :-) And make sure that you understand, asserts are not any good unless NDEBUG is set. They're good for catching problems during development (or for homework assignments) but, for robust code, they're not the best.

Comment: @paxdiablo isn't it the other way around, i.e. `#define NDEBUG` disables assertions?

Comment: @vsoftco, apologies, you're correct. That just shows how much I use assert :-)

Answer (score 5):

Variable-length arrays are not allowed in Standard C++. Use either a dynamic array, or better, `std::vector<int> data(capacity)`.

Also, you should initialize your member variables using a constructor initializer list,

```
stack(): capacity(100), data(capacity), top(0), bottom(0){} // assuming you use `std::vector<int> data;`
```

If you cannot use a `std::vector` (homework, otherwise you should!), then you can use a dynamic array

```
int* data;
```

and declare your constructor as

```
stack(): capacity(100), data(new int[capacity]), top(0), bottom(0){}
```

Then, you have to declare a destructor

```
~stack() { delete[] data;}
```

so you don't have memory leaks. Next you should also define your copy constructor and assignment operator, so things become a bit complicated. Just use `std::vector<int>` if you can.

Comment: in b4 "but my assignment says it's forbidden to use a vector"

Comment: Also think about what `int capacity;` and `int data[capacity];` would mean: data is sized according to capacity and capacity can't possibly have been assigned any value yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
int data[capacity];
```

is being actioned at *compile* time, long before `capacity` has a known value.

Probably the simplest solution, if you have to use an array and all object will have the same capacity (as seems to be the case with your current constructor), would be to change your variable declaration to:

```
static const int capacity = 100;
```

That will effectively allow it to be used as a compile-time constant, and your error disappears.

---

If you're limited to arrays and each object need a potentially *different* capacity, the usual way to do this is to dynamically allocate what you need in the constructor. First, make `data` a simple pointer:

```
int *data;
```

Then, in your constructor:

```
top=0;
bottom=0;
capacity=100;
data = new int[capacity];  // do this to create it.
```

Just remember to `delete[] data` in your destructor, and obey the rule of 3 (or 5 nowadays), ensuring you add other needed methods like copy/move constructors and copy/move assignment operators. Without those, you may find objects sharing the underlying data, usually a *very* bad idea.

---

However, you should keep in mind that seasoned coders will more likely use the full power of the C++ language/library and use a `vector` instead. These are far more adaptable than arrays and you'll be recognised by your colleagues as a true C++ programmer rather than a C+ one :-)